# Update bigquery table soon after insert records in Table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a requirement to load the data after a few minutes I need to update the record, how can I achieve that?? I am getting google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 UPDATE or DELETE statement over table dataset.tablename would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported

Is there any way to flush the data from streaming buffer to permanent storage??

````
I tried below option but this query also getting the same error.
UPDATE dataset.tablename
SET _PARTITIONTIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL```
````

Answer (score 0):

Streamed data is not immediately available for operations outside of analysis (select) for up to 90 minutes (typically much less). You can use streamingBuffer.oldestEntryTime to see the age of the oldest row in the streaming buffer in the tables.get response.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability

As a potential workaround, you could create an independent table with desired changes and join it in a query/view with the table you're streaming to, to see newer values in your query results. Eventually, you could use the "change" table to merge changes into the original table.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement